# Error 503 backend fetch failed while i am trying to download

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I have a haproxy-varnish setup for my ASPNET Core Web application and my application sending request via haproxy.conf file to the varnish. I can download all downloadable files except one url `/Payroll/Export/EmployeeAllDataExport?...`. File format is `.xlsx`. Tranfer-encoding header added manually by someone else so maybe that change refers the problem but i couldn't resolve until now.

I am sharing `varnishlog -g request -q "RespStatus == 503"` output, `default.vcl` file and releated lines in `haproxy.cfg`

P.S: If i disable varnish request from haproxy i can download the file but i need to do it with varnish and there is a problem for only one url not in an entire application.

> varnishlog output:

```
*   << Request  >> 1384717
-   Begin          req 1384716 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1658919403.185251 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1658919403.185251 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       $IP1 43974 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /Payroll/Report/EmployeeAllDataExport?1658919403106
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: $URL1
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
-   ReqHeader      Referer: https://$URL1/Payroll/Report/EmployeeAllData?sitemap=63f8e1f5-a873-4cb5-8a5c-16b79863da33
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: CurrentLanguage=tr; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.9TtSrW0hzOs=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85n139G92-PEfuGVynC-Lh4dd-5XOYoILAhHGAD6DW-my0vgWvin4bBKCLT-GFQonAQCvkTZV8EuOB8s6RPOunsRFPpgucKPwKQSmF7Syx0tg8TubZs_Xw6qTxh9gVq03lo; Hcm=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85lmo
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: $IP2
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: $IP2
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: $IP2, $IP1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqUnset       Host: $URL1
-   ReqHeader      Host: $URL1
-   ReqURL         /Payroll/Report/EmployeeAllDataExport?1658919403106
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: CurrentLanguage=tr; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.9TtSrW0hzOs=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85n139G92-PEfuGVynC-Lh4dd-5XOYoILAhHGAD6DW-my0vgWvin4bBKCLT-GFQonAQCvkTZV8EuOB8s6RPOunsRFPpgucKPwKQSmF7Syx0tg8TubZs_Xw6qTxh9gVq03lo; Hcm=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85lmo
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: CurrentLanguage=tr; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.9TtSrW0hzOs=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85n139G92-PEfuGVynC-Lh4dd-5XOYoILAhHGAD6DW-my0vgWvin4bBKCLT-GFQonAQCvkTZV8EuOB8s6RPOunsRFPpgucKPwKQSmF7Syx0tg8TubZs_Xw6qTxh9gVq03lo; Hcm=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85lmo
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: CurrentLanguage=tr; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.9TtSrW0hzOs=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85n139G92-PEfuGVynC-Lh4dd-5XOYoILAhHGAD6DW-my0vgWvin4bBKCLT-GFQonAQCvkTZV8EuOB8s6RPOunsRFPpgucKPwKQSmF7Syx0tg8TubZs_Xw6qTxh9gVq03lo; Hcm=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85lmo
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: CurrentLanguage=tr; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.9TtSrW0hzOs=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85n139G92-PEfuGVynC-Lh4dd-5XOYoILAhHGAD6DW-my0vgWvin4bBKCLT-GFQonAQCvkTZV8EuOB8s6RPOunsRFPpgucKPwKQSmF7Syx0tg8TubZs_Xw6qTxh9gVq03lo; Hcm=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85lmo
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: CurrentLanguage=tr; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.9TtSrW0hzOs=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85n139G92-PEfuGVynC-Lh4dd-5XOYoILAhHGAD6DW-my0vgWvin4bBKCLT-GFQonAQCvkTZV8EuOB8s6RPOunsRFPpgucKPwKQSmF7Syx0tg8TubZs_Xw6qTxh9gVq03lo; Hcm=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85lmo
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: CurrentLanguage=tr; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.9TtSrW0hzOs=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85n139G92-PEfuGVynC-Lh4dd-5XOYoILAhHGAD6DW-my0vgWvin4bBKCLT-GFQonAQCvkTZV8EuOB8s6RPOunsRFPpgucKPwKQSmF7Syx0tg8TubZs_Xw6qTxh9gVq03lo; Hcm=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85lmo
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: CurrentLanguage=tr; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.9TtSrW0hzOs=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85n139G92-PEfuGVynC-Lh4dd-5XOYoILAhHGAD6DW-my0vgWvin4bBKCLT-GFQonAQCvkTZV8EuOB8s6RPOunsRFPpgucKPwKQSmF7Syx0tg8TubZs_Xw6qTxh9gVq03lo; Hcm=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85lmo
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: CurrentLanguage=tr; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.9TtSrW0hzOs=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85n139G92-PEfuGVynC-Lh4dd-5XOYoILAhHGAD6DW-my0vgWvin4bBKCLT-GFQonAQCvkTZV8EuOB8s6RPOunsRFPpgucKPwKQSmF7Syx0tg8TubZs_Xw6qTxh9gVq03lo; Hcm=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85lmo
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: CurrentLanguage=tr; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.9TtSrW0hzOs=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85n139G92-PEfuGVynC-Lh4dd-5XOYoILAhHGAD6DW-my0vgWvin4bBKCLT-GFQonAQCvkTZV8EuOB8s6RPOunsRFPpgucKPwKQSmF7Syx0tg8TubZs_Xw6qTxh9gVq03lo; Hcm=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85lmo
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: CurrentLanguage=tr; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.9TtSrW0hzOs=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85n139G92-PEfuGVynC-Lh4dd-5XOYoILAhHGAD6DW-my0vgWvin4bBKCLT-GFQonAQCvkTZV8EuOB8s6RPOunsRFPpgucKPwKQSmF7Syx0tg8TubZs_Xw6qTxh9gVq03lo; Hcm=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85lmo
-   ReqHeader      Surrogate-Capability: key=ESI/1.0
-   VCL_return     hash
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 1384718 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1658919404.932211 1.746959 1.746959
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     503
-   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 27 Jul 2022 10:56:44 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 1384717
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.2)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespHeader     X-Cache: MISS
-   RespHeader     X-Cache-Hits: 0
-   RespUnset      Server: Varnish
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 1384717
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.2)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1658919404.932258 1.747006 0.000047
-   Filters
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 284
-   RespHeader     Connection: close
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1658919404.932344 1.747092 0.000086
-   ReqAcct        5695 0 5695 210 284 494
-   End
**  << BeReq    >> 1384718
--  Begin          bereq 1384717 fetch
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1658919403.185407 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /Payroll/Report/EmployeeAllDataExport?1658919403106
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"
--  BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
--  BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
--  BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
--  BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
--  BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
--  BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
--  BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
--  BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
--  BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
--  BereqHeader    Referer: https://$URL1/Payroll/Report/EmployeeAllData?sitemap=63f8e1f5-a873-4cb5-8a5c-16b79863da33
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Port: 443
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: $IP1, $IP2
--  BereqHeader    Host: $URL1
--  BereqHeader    Cookie: CurrentLanguage=tr; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.9TtSrW0hzOs=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85n139G92-PEfuGVynC-Lh4dd-5XOYoILAhHGAD6DW-my0vgWvin4bBKCLT-GFQonAQCvkTZV8EuOB8s6RPOunsRFPpgucKPwKQSmF7Syx0tg8TubZs_Xw6qTxh9gVq03lo; Hcm=CfDJ8E7lWAHTLKBOsOUJGWpm85lmo
--  BereqHeader    Surrogate-Capability: key=ESI/1.0
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 1384718
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  BackendOpen    31 haproxy $IP1 8585 $IP3 52722
--  BackendStart   $IP1 8585
--  Timestamp      Bereq: 1658919403.185494 0.000087 0.000087
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1658919404.931989 1.746582 1.746495
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   200
--  BerespReason   OK
--  BerespHeader   Connection: close
--  BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 27 Jul 2022 10:56:44 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
--  BerespHeader   Server: Kestrel
--  BerespHeader   Transfer-Encoding: identity
--  BerespHeader   Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
--  BerespHeader   content-disposition: attachment;  filename="$Filename.xlsx"
--  BackendClose   31 haproxy
--  Error          Body cannot be fetched
--  Timestamp      Error: 1658919404.932043 1.746636 0.000054
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   503
--  BerespReason   Service Unavailable
--  BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
--  BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 27 Jul 2022 10:56:44 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
--  BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
--  BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Storage        malloc Transient
--  Length         284
--  BereqAcct      5731 0 5731 327 0 327
--  End
```

> default.vcl

```
vcl 4.1;
# Based on: https://github.com/mattiasgeniar/varnish-6.0-configuration-templates/blob/master/default.vcl

import std;
import directors;

backend haproxy { # Define one backend
  .host = "10.10.0.117";    # IP or Hostname of backend
  .port = "8585";           # Port Apache or whatever is listening
  .max_connections = 300; # That's it

  .first_byte_timeout     = 300s;   # How long to wait before we receive a first byte from our backend?
  .connect_timeout        = 300s;     # How long to wait for a backend connection?
  .between_bytes_timeout  = 300s;     # How long to wait between bytes received from our backend?
}

acl purge {
  "localhost";
  "127.0.0.1";
  "::1";
}

sub vcl_init {

  new vdir = directors.round_robin();
  vdir.add_backend(haproxy);
}

sub vcl_recv {

  #if (req.url ~ "^/Payroll/Report") {
  # return(pipe);
  #}

  set req.backend_hint = vdir.backend(); # send all traffic to the vdir director

  if (req.http.Host) {
   set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");
  }

  unset req.http.proxy;

  set req.url = std.querysort(req.url);

  if (req.method == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
      return (synth(405, "This IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests."));
    }
    return (purge);
  }

  # Only deal with "normal" types
  if (req.method != "GET" &&
      req.method != "HEAD" &&
      req.method != "PUT" &&
      req.method != "POST" &&
      req.method != "TRACE" &&
      req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
      req.method != "PATCH" &&
      req.method != "DELETE" ){
    /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
    return (pipe);
  }

  # Implementing websocket support (https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/users-guide/vcl-example-websockets.html)
  if (req.http.Upgrade ~ "(?i)websocket") {
    return (pipe);
  }

  # Only cache GET or HEAD requests. This makes sure the POST requests are always passed.
  if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
    return (pass);
  }

  if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "&(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "");
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "\?(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "?");
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?&", "?");
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
  }

  # Strip hash, server doesn't need it.
  if (req.url ~ "\#") {
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\#.*$", "");
  }

  # Strip a trailing ? if it exists
  if (req.url ~ "\?$") {
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
  }

  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "has_js=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__gads=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__qc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__atuv.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");


  if (req.http.cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
  }

  if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bz2|flac|flv|gz|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|ogg|ogm|opus|rar|tar|tgz|tbz|txz|wav|webm|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
    return (hash);
  }

  # Remove all cookies for static files
  # A valid discussion could be held on this line: do you really need to cache static files that don't cause load? Only if you have memory left.
  # Sure, there's disk I/O, but chances are your OS will already have these files in their buffers (thus memory).
  # Before you blindly enable this, have a read here: https://ma.ttias.be/stop-caching-static-files/
  if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|apng|webp|avi|bmp|bz2|css|csv|doc|docx|eot|flac|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|odt|otf|ogg|ogm|opus|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tbz|tgz|ttf|txt|txz|wav|webm|webp|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
    return (hash);
  }


  #if (req.url ~ "^/Payroll/Report") {
  #  unset req.http.Cookie;
  #  return (hash);
  #}
  # Send Surrogate-Capability headers to announce ESI support to backend
  set req.http.Surrogate-Capability = "key=ESI/1.0";

  if (req.http.Authorization) {
    # Not cacheable by default
    return (pass);
  }
  if (req.url ~ "(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|tiff|bmp|apng|webp)$") {
    return (pipe);
  }

  return (hash);
}

sub vcl_pipe {
  # Called upon entering pipe mode.
  # In this mode, the request is passed on to the backend, and any further data from both the client
  # and backend is passed on unaltered until either end closes the connection. Basically, Varnish will
  # degrade into a simple TCP proxy, shuffling bytes back and forth. For a connection in pipe mode,
  # no other VCL subroutine will ever get called after vcl_pipe.

  # Note that only the first request to the backend will have
  # X-Forwarded-For set.  If you use X-Forwarded-For and want to
  # have it set for all requests, make sure to have:
  # set bereq.http.connection = "close";
  # here.  It is not set by default as it might break some broken web
  # applications, like IIS with NTLM authentication.

  # set bereq.http.Connection = "Close";

  # Implementing websocket support (https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/users-guide/vcl-example-websockets.html)
  if (req.http.upgrade) {
    set bereq.http.upgrade = req.http.upgrade;
  }

  return (pipe);
}

sub vcl_pass {
  # Called upon entering pass mode. In this mode, the request is passed on to the backend, and the
  # backend's response is passed on to the client, but is not entered into the cache. Subsequent
  # requests submitted over the same client connection are handled normally.

  # return (pass);
}

# The data on which the hashing will take place
sub vcl_hash {
  # Called after vcl_recv to create a hash value for the request. This is used as a key
  # to look up the object in Varnish.

  hash_data(req.url);

  if (req.http.host) {
    hash_data(req.http.host);
  } else {
    hash_data(server.ip);
  }

  # hash cookies for requests that have them
  if (req.http.Cookie) {
    hash_data(req.http.Cookie);
  }

  # Cache the HTTP vs HTTPs separately
  if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
    hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
  }
}

sub vcl_hit {
  # Called when a cache lookup is successful.

  if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
    # A pure unadultered hit, deliver it
    return (deliver);
  }

  # https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-grace.html
  # When several clients are requesting the same page Varnish will send one request to the backend and place the others
  # on hold while fetching one copy from the backend. In some products this is called request coalescing and Varnish does
  # this automatically.
  # If you are serving thousands of hits per second the queue of waiting requests can get huge. There are two potential
  # problems - one is a thundering herd problem - suddenly releasing a thousand threads to serve content might send the
  # load sky high. Secondly - nobody likes to wait. To deal with this we can instruct Varnish to keep the objects in cache
  # beyond their TTL and to serve the waiting requests somewhat stale content.

# if (!std.healthy(req.backend_hint) && (obj.ttl + obj.grace > 0s)) {
#   return (deliver);
# } else {
#   return (miss);
# }

  # We have no fresh fish. Lets look at the stale ones.
  if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
    # Backend is healthy. Limit age to 10s.
    if (obj.ttl + 10s > 0s) {
      #set req.http.grace = "normal(limited)";
      return (deliver);
    }
  } else {
    # backend is sick - use full grace
      if (obj.ttl + obj.grace > 0s) {
        #set req.http.grace = "full";
        return (deliver);
      }
  }
}

sub vcl_miss {
  # Called after a cache lookup if the requested document was not found in the cache. Its purpose
  # is to decide whether or not to attempt to retrieve the document from the backend, and which
  # backend to use.

  return (fetch);
}

# Handle the HTTP request coming from our backend
sub vcl_backend_response {
  # Called after the response headers has been successfully retrieved from the backend.

  # Pause ESI request and remove Surrogate-Control header
  if (beresp.http.Surrogate-Control ~ "ESI/1.0") {
    unset beresp.http.Surrogate-Control;
    set beresp.do_esi = true;
  }


  # Enable cache for all static files
  # The same argument as the static caches from above: monitor your cache size, if you get data nuked out of it, consider giving up the static file cache.
  # Before you blindly enable this, have a read here: https://ma.ttias.be/stop-caching-static-files/
  if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bmp|bz2|css|csv|doc|docx|eot|flac|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|odt|otf|ogg|ogm|opus|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tbz|tgz|ttf|txt|txz|wav|webm|webp|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
  }

  #if (bereq.url ~ "^/Payroll/Report") {
  #  unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
  #}

  # Large static files are delivered directly to the end-user without
  # waiting for Varnish to fully read the file first.
  # Varnish 4 fully supports Streaming, so use streaming here to avoid locking.
  if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bz2|flac|flv|gz|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|ogg|ogm|opus|rar|tar|tgz|tbz|txz|wav|webm|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    set beresp.do_stream = true;  # Check memory usage it'll grow in fetch_chunksize blocks (128k by default) if the backend doesn't send a Content-Length header, so only enable it for big objects
  }

  # Sometimes, a 301 or 302 redirect formed via Apache's mod_rewrite can mess with the HTTP port that is being passed along.
  # This often happens with simple rewrite rules in a scenario where Varnish runs on :80 and Apache on :8080 on the same box.
  # A redirect can then often redirect the end-user to a URL on :8080, where it should be :80.
  # This may need finetuning on your setup.
  #
  # To prevent accidental replace, we only filter the 301/302 redirects for now.
  if (beresp.status == 301 || beresp.status == 302) {
    set beresp.http.Location = regsub(beresp.http.Location, ":[0-9]+", "");
  }

  # Set 2min cache if unset for static files
  if (beresp.ttl <= 0s || beresp.http.Set-Cookie || beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
    set beresp.ttl = 120s; # Important, you shouldn't rely on this, SET YOUR HEADERS in the backend
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    return (deliver);
  }

  # Don't cache 50x responses
  if (beresp.status == 500 || beresp.status == 502 || beresp.status == 503 || beresp.status == 504) {
    return (abandon);
  }

  # Allow stale content, in case the backend goes down.
  # make Varnish keep all objects for 6 hours beyond their TTL
  set beresp.grace = 6h;

  return (deliver);
}

# The routine when we deliver the HTTP request to the user
# Last chance to modify headers that are sent to the client
sub vcl_deliver {
  # Called before a cached object is delivered to the client.
  if (obj.hits > 0) { # Add debug header to see if it's a HIT/MISS and the number of hits, disable when not needed
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
  } else {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
  }

  # Please note that obj.hits behaviour changed in 4.0, now it counts per objecthead, not per object
  # and obj.hits may not be reset in some cases where bans are in use. See bug 1492 for details.
  # So take hits with a grain of salt
  set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;

  # Remove some headers: PHP version
  unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;

  # Remove some headers: Apache version & OS
  unset resp.http.Server;
  unset resp.http.X-Drupal-Cache;
  unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
  unset resp.http.Via;
  unset resp.http.Link;
  unset resp.http.X-Generator;

  return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_purge {
  # Only handle actual PURGE HTTP methods, everything else is discarded
  if (req.method == "PURGE") {
    # restart request
    set req.http.X-Purge = "Yes";
    return(restart);
  }
}

sub vcl_synth {
  if (resp.status == 720) {
    # We use this special error status 720 to force redirects with 301 (permanent) redirects
    # To use this, call the following from anywhere in vcl_recv: return (synth(720, "http://host/new.html"));
    set resp.http.Location = resp.reason;
    set resp.status = 301;
    return (deliver);
  } elseif (resp.status == 721) {
    # And we use error status 721 to force redirects with a 302 (temporary) redirect
    # To use this, call the following from anywhere in vcl_recv: return (synth(720, "http://host/new.html"));
    set resp.http.Location = resp.reason;
    set resp.status = 302;
    return (deliver);
  }

  return (deliver);
}


sub vcl_fini {
  # Called when VCL is discarded only after all requests have exited the VCL.
  # Typically used to clean up VMODs.

  return (ok);
}
```

P.S: please consider i tried `if(req.url ~ $URL){return (pass);} or pipe and if(bereq.url ~ $URL){unset beresp.http.set-cookie;}`. Those lines which i tried now command line at the default.vcl file.

> haproxy.cfg

```
frontend HTTP
    bind *:80

    redirect scheme https if { hdr(Host) -i $URL1 } !{ ssl_fc }

frontend returning-varnish # returning traffic from varnish
    bind :8585
                #acl $Backend1 hdr(host) -i $URL1
                #use_backend $Backend1 if $Backend1

frontend HTTPS
        bind *:443 ssl crt $Directory1 crt $Directory2

#       http-request lua.cors
#       http-response lua.cors "GET,PUT,POST" "localhost:1907"
#       http-response lua.cors "GET,PUT,POST" "*"

        http-response add-header Access-Control-Allow-Origin %[capture.req.hdr(0)] if { capture.req.hdr(0) -m found }
        rspadd Content-Security-Policy:\ upgrade-insecure-requests
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
        #rspadd Strict-Transport-Security:\ max-age=31536000
        http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; always;"

        maxconn 100000

        redirect prefix https://$URL2 if { hdr(host) -i $URL4 }
        redirect prefix https://$URL3 if { hdr(host) -i $URL4 }

    #use_backend    Varnish if $Backend1
        use_backend     $Backend1 if $Backend1

backend Varnish
        http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
        http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
        server varnish1 $IP2:6081 check

backend $Backend1
        mode    http
        balance leastconn

        server $Server $Application_Ip:31717 check inter 1s rise 2 fall 2
```

P.S: Because of the varnish is not working while I want to download file, I made those lines as a command line at haproxy.cfg file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs I'm assuming the response headers of your backend response are not properly formatted.

The VSL error is the following:

```
--  Error          Body cannot be fetched
```

Your backend response doesn't include a `Content-Length` header, which is fine. But if you don't return a buffered response, Varnish looks at the `Transfer-Encoding` header to see whether or not you'r using *Chunked Transfer Encoding*.

This is the header your application is returning:

```
--  BerespHeader   Transfer-Encoding: identity
```

When we take a look at the code, specifically this line https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/55753f98b1b392766bd4baed7eb684c006225f57/bin/varnishd/http1/cache_http1_proto.c#L319, you can see that Varnish throws the error because it doesn't recognize the transfer encoding.

Please set a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header and Varnish will have no issue with this response and will stream the content through based on how your backend flushes the various chunks of content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thijs Feryn. As i understood from your answer, i ensured that my added header is 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' and my varnish already has some other 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' requests with comleting errorless. However still header shown as 'Transfer-Encoding: identity' in the log and i am taking exact same log. However i think i should say, if i make a command line to lines 'if(req.url ~ URL){return(pass)}' and other two, i am not getting any logs but 503 backend fetch failed error still there. I thought 'varnishlog -q "RespStatus == 503" -g request' command not works

Comment: You won't solve the problem by just changing the `Transfer-Encoding` header to `Chunked`, because then your web server or application would actually have to send over the chunks separately. Please figure out why your application is sending out the `Transfer-Encoding: identity` value and make sure it no longer does. Search your code, search your config, search your web server settings and figure that out. Determine if it's your application that doing this or your webserver.